# Ruby on Rails - Hash of Arrays, group by and sum by with many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have a similar problem with this topic 
[Ruby on Rails - Hash of Arrays, group by and sum by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500280/ruby-on-rails-hash-of-arrays-group-by-and-sum-by-column-name)

However, my problem is that group by and sum by with many columns instead of one.

For example: my hashes

```
[
    {"idx"=>"1234", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"idx"=>"1235", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"idx"=>"1235", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00002", "order1"=>"2"}
]
```

The result like this

```
[
    {"idx"=>"1234", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"6.00", "money1"=>"2.00","order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"idx"=>"1234", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00","order"=>"00002", "order1"=>"2"}
]
```

a call like this `group_hashes arr, ["order","order1"], ["money","money1"]`

I tried a loop inside merge! However, the result is wrong. 
Please teach me solve this case. Sorry for my stupid mind.

Comment: Why `money1` become `3.00`. I though they should be `2.00` and `1.00`.

Comment: @falsetru you're right! thats my mistake.

Comment: @falsetru I have another problem like this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469348/ruby-how-to-retrieve-sum-in-array-group-by-multiple-keys-with-condition-max/ Could you take a look? Thank again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usnig [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), you can iterate arrays of hashes grouped by `order`, `order1` key.

Then merge hashes (by summing up `money`, `money1` entries):

```
a = [
  {"idx"=>"1234", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
  {"idx"=>"1235", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
  {"idx"=>"1235", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"00002", "order1"=>"2"}
]
a.group_by { |x| x.values_at('order', 'order1') }.map {|key, hashes|
  result = hashes[0].clone
  ['money', 'money1'].each { |key|
    result[key] = hashes.inject(0) { |s, x| s + x[key].to_f }
  }
  result
}
# => [{"idx"=>"1234", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>6.0, "money1"=>2.0, "order"=>"00001", "order1"=>"1"},
#     {"idx"=>"1235", "account"=>"abde", "money"=>3.0, "money1"=>1.0, "order"=>"00002", "order1"=>"2"}]
```

---

```
group_keys = ['order', 'order1']
sum_keys = ['money', 'money1']
a.group_by { |x| x.values_at(*group_keys) }.map {|key, hashes|
  result = hashes[0].clone
  sum_keys.each { |key|
    result[key] = hashes.inject(0) { |s, x| s + x[key].to_f }
  }
  result
}
```

Comment: Working. But, I not see key "order1" in result.

Comment: @VuLe, I don't understand what you mean: `not see key "order1" in result.`

Comment: @VuLe, See this: https://ideone.com/BQQSVz . I can see `order1` in the resulting output.

Comment: I just print out the result. I dont see the "order1" key [{..., "order1" => "1"}, {..., "order1" => "2"}].

Comment: @VuLe, As you can see in the link, I can see the `order1` key. Could you post another question with the exact code, and the output, and expected output?

Comment: with your link, I can see the `code`order1`/code` key. I run your code on [link]tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php[/link] with name your code is method `code`def foo arr ... end`/code`, then call `code`a = foo arr`/code` and `code`p a`/code`. At last, I think not need post another question, because your answer is enough.